# R: help directing to an object, not an atomic vector

Tags: r, object, phylogeny

I have a large set of phylogenetic trees (phylo objects) which I am attempting to compare. The name of each comparison is stored in the list `Newick`and the number of the two files are stored in the matrix `cc[1:2,i]`.

However, when I try to run `all.equal.phylo(Newick[[cc[1,i]]], Newick[[cc[2,i]]])` I get an error message saying that "Error in target$tip.label : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors", meaning that `Newick[[cc[]]]` being treated as the object rather than directing to the actual phylo object.

For example, I hope to get `Newick[[cc[1,1]]]` when `cc[1,1] = 1` to direct to the phylo object `Newick1` rather than an atomic vector `"Newick1"`.

How can I resolve this issue? Thank you very much!

Additional note: `all.equal.phylo(Newick1,Newick2)` works while `all.equal.phylo(Newick[[cc[1,1]]], Newick[[cc[1,2]]])` does not even though `Newick[[cc[1,1]]]` returns "Newick1" and `Newick[[cc[1,2]]]` returns "Newick2".
I've tried removing the quotation marks using noquote, but it will still not direct to the actual phylo object.

Comment: If `Newick[[cc[1,1]]]`  returns `"Newick1"`, then that is a character value. There are no quotation marks the value you see on the console as "Newick1". That just how the print method displays character objects. You nwill need to do a better job of describing these objects. Suggest using `str` or `dput`.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure how I would use `str` or `dput` to change the output of `Newick[[cc[1,1]]]` from a character value into something that would be interpretted as the object `Newick1`

Comment: Your question at the moment provide precious little information about the `Newick` object. I'm suggesting you use `st`r and/or `dput` to remedy that deficiency in your abilities to convey that information in language that we understand. At the moment it appears that "Newick1" is only a name rather than an actual first class R object. On the other hand you say that `all.equal.phylo(Newick1,Newick2)` "works" (whatever that means) so it remains possible that there is actually such an object.